# Flutter - Debugging iOS 14 background message (when the app is closed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-debug

Trying to build a chat app, which gets FCM messages and shows notifications even when the app is closed.
Clearly, something in my top-level onBackgroundMessage function for FCM is wrong as the notifications are not showing (on a physical device- iOS emulators don't work with FCM).

In Android, I've debugged a similar situation by using adb logcat (and logs/print command).
Obviously, adb isn't available for an iPhone, and I don't know how to see the logs after the app is closed (I've tried to look at the console at Xcode but no Flutter messages are showing).
Because I can't run the app again after it's closed (see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ios-14 the application can no longer be re-launched by tapping the application’s icon) I'm installing it on my device via "flutter install release".

How do I see the logs after install release, or otherwise how can I debug functionality (at least view flutter's logs and prints) when the app is closed?